# Do social media widgets have any effect on search engine optimisation?

Tags: seo, social-media

Facebook and other social media platforms have developed social media widgets which are aesthetically pleasing but have quite a lot of dynamic content being loaded. With this in mind, would it be a positive or negative effect on the website's ranking in search engine results if they have this installed on a given page?

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

Comment: Short answer? No! See my answer here. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102172/will-putting-a-clock-display-on-a-website-boost-seo/102181#102181 While the questions are not an exact match, they are darn close. Cheers!!

Comment: I will probably avoid iframe content, which make my pagespeed slower.

Comment: See also: [Facebook like and share buttons will have impact on SEO in future?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43851/facebook-like-and-share-buttons-will-have-impact-on-seo-in-future) and [What is the way to properly implement a Facebook Like button on a page for best SEO purposes?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/what-is-the-way-to-properly-implement-a-facebook-like-button-on-a-page-for-best)

Answer (score 3):

Officially, social media does not have an impact (per Google). However, web site plugins that link people to social media sites may have an impact on click through rates, if enough people use them. And if that share drives more traffic to your web page, then that will count. On the social media side of the action, if the user spends time on the Facebook/Instagram/Twitter site you may see benefits from pages or content that includes your business. I'm not sure how the referral pages would show, because depending on how the plugin is coded it may or may not pass a clean URL that Google could pick up as a referral page.

Regardless of the official word, I look at is as additional traffic is not a bad thing, in particular if it gets you repeat visitors to your actual site.

Comment: The OP is asking about an installed FB widget on a web page and not about social media in general.

Comment: @closetnoc Revised answer

Comment: It is easy to misread a question. We have all done it! Cheers!! Nicely done.